# Generate CSV from List of Objects

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, csv

I am trying to generate a CSV from the results of a hibernate query, it could contain up to 200k rows, and when created the CSV could be around 30MB.

I am struggling to get the performance anything near acceptable.
Currently my hibernate query will return a list of objects.
I am then using a StringBuilder to generate a CSV string.
Then I get a byte array from that, and pass the byte array into response.outputstream.write() method.

What should I be doing in order to generate a CSV of this size efficiently?

My Service

```
List<Object> objectList = hibernateDao.getObjectList(objectList);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("field1_id,field2,field3,field14");
    for(Object object : objectList){
        sb.append("\n");
        sb.append(object.field1());
        sb.append(",");
        sb.append(object.field2());
        sb.append(",");
        sb.append(object.field3());
        ...
        ...
        sb.append(",");
        sb.append(object.field14);
    }
    byte[] bytes = sb.toString().getBytes();
    return bytes;
```

My Controller will get the resulting bytes[]

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/comma-separated-values");
response.getOutputStream().write(objectService.getListByteArray());
```

Comment: use streaming the whole way through. don't build a huge file in memory then stream it. stream it right from the database to your response. super csv is pretty fast

Answer (score 0):

The problem initially appears to be on your `StringBuilder` expanding, you could initialize it to allocate big number of characters but then the length of the content you are trying to write might go over `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (the maximum length of a `char[]`) and you'll get a buffer overflow error.

There's also the potential problem of escaping commas and quote characters in the values you are writing individually. This is tricky to handle and I suggest you to use a CSV library to make sure you get the correct output.

Try [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) to persist your objects. You can use a few annotations to serialize specific fields to CSV.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library, it's open-source and free (Apache 2.0 license)